# Efficient way to aggregate values of a column were value is specific value

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

A quick example

```
a <- c(1,1,2)
b <- c(1000,200,20)
c <- c(10,20,10)
myframe <- data.frame(a,b,c)

> myframe
  a    b  c
1 1 1000 10
2 1  200 20
3 2   20 10
```

I now want to aggregate the values of column c where the value of column a equals `1`. The result should consequently be `30`.

Just a word to the original data the dataframe has about 100,000 rows and 400 columns. The values rows to aggregate pop up about 10-30 times in the data.

Comment: Do you want to only sum up column c for all rows where column a == 1 ? or for each unique entry in column a?

Answer (score 4):

Sum the values of `c` where `a == 1`.

```
with(myframe, sum(c[a == 1]))
# [1] 30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a very big data set maybe use `data.table` [binary search](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf) (although it seems @Svens solution will be efficient enough)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(myframe), a)[J(1), sum(c)]
# [1] 30
```

In order to illustrate the difference, one can show that for a data set of 1MM rows, **binary search is faster by a factor of 6~**

```
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e6
a <- sample(1e3, n, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(1e4, n, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(1e2, n, replace = TRUE)
myframe <- data.frame(a,b,c)
myframe2 <- copy(myframe)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(Sven = with(myframe, sum(c[a == 1])),
               David = setkey(setDT(myframe2), a)[J(1), sum(c)])
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  Sven 28.020912 30.171903 32.858967 31.464116 32.766395 71.02099   100
# David  3.696436  4.080331  5.719189  4.469356  6.167174 43.38575   100
```

Comment: @akrun, I changed it to binary search, otherwise I don't see any reason to not just use base R

Answer (score 0):

'aggregate' function can be used:

```
> aggregate(c~a, data=myframe, sum)
  a  c
1 1 30
2 2 10
```

data.table version:

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(myframe)[,list(sum=sum(c)),by=a]
   a sum
1: 1  30
2: 2  10
```